# EF: The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Cards_Sellers_SellerId"

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

The database was created with Code-First. I want to add a relationship between Seller and Card later, but I get the following error, how can I fix it? Since there is data in the database, I do not want to delete the database and try again.
Note: I'm only using efcore and code-first.

*The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Cards_Sellers_SellerId". The conflict occurred in database "OrdeDb", table "AdminDb.Sellers", column 'Id'.*

```
public class Card : BaseEntity
    {
        public Card()
        {
            CardItems = new List<CardItem>();
        }
        public double? TotalPrice { get; set; } 
        public int? AppUserId { get; set; }
        public AppUser? AppUser { get; set; }
        public int? CouponId { get; set; }
        public Coupon? Coupon { get; set; }
        public int? SellerId { get; set; }
        public Seller? Seller { get; set; }
        public List<CardItem> CardItems { get; set; }
    }
```

```
  public class Seller : BaseEntity
    {
        public Seller()
        {
            AppUsers = new List<AppUser>();         
            Cards= new List<Card>();
        }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? SurName { get; set; }
        public string? Address { get; set; }
        public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public List<Card> Cards { get; set; }
    }
```

I applied the changes by saying add-migration, but when I said update-database I got the error I mentioned.

Comment: Could you show the details of the Id property of Seller Entity?

Comment: i solved, i removed last migration and tryed again, its worked.